# QWebView in QDockWidget refuses to resize

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

This bad boy just does not want to change size to fill the dock widget area.  I have tried all sorts of variations with QSizePolicy but nothing seems to work.  The size of the QWebView always stays the same.  Do I need to write a resize() callback?

Here's what I have right now:

```
    self.helpwindow = QtGui.QDockWidget("Doc Browser")
    self.helpwindow.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
    self.helpwindow.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable | QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable)
    helpAction = self.helpwindow.toggleViewAction()
    helpAction.setText("&Help Browser")
    helpAction.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("F1"))
    helpMenu.addAction(helpAction)

    self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.helpwindow)      

    helpbrowser = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.helpwindow)
    indexpath = resource_filename(__name__,"help/index.html")
    url = QtCore.QUrl("file://" + indexpath)
    helpbrowser.load(url)
    helpbrowser.show()
    helpbrowser.updateGeometry()
    helpbrowser.update()

    helpbrowser.setMinimumWidth(400)
    helpbrowser.setMinimumHeight( self.helpwindow.height())
    sizepolicy = helpbrowser.sizePolicy()
    sizepolicy.setVerticalPolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
    sizepolicy.setHorizontalPolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
```

I'm using PyQT4 but C++ solutions gladly accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting only paren't wont make QDockWidget manage child widget. You need to call:

```
helpwindow.setWidget(helpbrowser)
```

Comment: Hot-dawg!  Thanks Kamil!  This was exactly the solution I needed.